# Node.Js 301 url-rewrite issues for Lambda@Edge function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301, static-site

moving my static site to a new domain and while at it need to remove the last slash from every url on the site and send a 301 response using a Lambda function. This is how it should look:

***oldsite.com/any-page/*** is going to be ***newsite.com/any-page***

I found a code example to help me change the domain but now every page on the old site will point to the homepage of the new site, disregarding the change path function.

This is the code I'm using right now, something isn't properly for the path switch:

```
'use strict';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  /*
   * Generate HTTP redirect response with 301 status code and Location header.
   */

   const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

   // get the original URL path
   const path = request.uri
   const baseURI = 'https://newsite.com'
// construct the response
   const response = {
      status: '301',
      statusDescription: 'Found',
      headers: {
          location: [{
              key: 'Location',
              value: baseURI,
          }],
      },
  };
// Configure the URL redirects
  switch(path) {
    case /\/.*\//:
      response.headers.location[0].value = baseURI + /\/.*/;
    break;

    default:
      response.headers.location[0].value = baseURI;
   }

  callback(null, response);
};
```

The culprit here seems to be the Regex since when I tried an actual path:

```
switch(path) {
    case '/foo/':
      response.headers.location[0].value = baseURI + '/foo';
    break;
```

It worked perfectly and made the switch. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

After digging and playing around I managed an actual code that works and seems even more efficient than the original one. It seems to do the job for me, at least for this specific use case. I may add more conditions to it as needed.

```
'use strict';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  /*
   * Generate HTTP redirect response with 301 status code and Location header.
   */

   const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

   // get the original URL path
   const baseURI = 'https://newsite.com'
   const path = request.uri.replace(/\/$/, '')
   const newURI = baseURI+path
// construct the response
   const response = {
      status: '301',
      statusDescription: 'Found',
      headers: {
          location: [{
              key: 'Location',
              value: newURI,
          }],
      },

  };

  callback(null, response);
};
```